# How to write test cases of an application which has almost same functionalities on its web and mobile app(ios + android)

Tags: manual-testing, android, testcase, web-application, ios

I am currently testing a chat application which is for both web and mobile devices. I have created test cases of a module for web application in Zephyr for Jira. Now I am a bit confused. Should I clone the test cases of web application for iOS and android? If I do that I would have to execute these test cases again on mobile devices. I want to save time but this is the only solution that I have in my mind. What can be done to write and execute these test cases for all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about it would be, yes, copy the test case/clarify that it needs to be validated against all three client environments.

It might seem redundant to test against the different environments in this case, but if it's application based then one must remember that the application is built on different architecture for the environments.

I this is not an application but strictly a web portal, then redundant testing would prove fruitless as it's all based on browser, and not device environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have pointed out clearly that the chat application meant for both web and mobile devices.

An application which is responsive has different UI views based on the environment in which it is opened up.You can write test cases for web portal first and 
then clone the test cases for mobile devices for execution.